# Proposing a solution: will or would?

Tags: conditionals, will-would

I am currently confused about the usage of "will" and "would", especially when proposing a solution.

For example, I want to promote recycling of plastic bottles to improve the environment.

Should I use:

- Recycling plastic bottles **will** improve our environment.
- Recycling plastic bottles **would** improve our environment.

In addition, I don't know which conditional sentence is correct:

- If the government **raise** taxes on alcohol, our lives **will** be better.
- If the government **raised** taxes on alcohol, our lives **would** be better.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), taking care to note the comments on search & research, including: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!" Better questions serve the ultimate purpose of SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will implies certainty; would is conditional.  But you need to think about what is conditional here.  It sounds like you are saying ‘if plastic bottles are recycled it will improve the environment’, but lacking the ‘if’ you are baking the conditionality into the word ‘would’.  ‘Chopping off heads would lead to death’ doesn’t make the death conditional if the heads are chopped.  Compare that to ‘if we chop off heads it will lead to death’.